# Datagridview Cellclick event

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Im using VB 2010. I have a `StudentsDatagriview` on my form.

When a user clicks the Columns Header to change the sort of data the `StudentsDataGridView_CellClick` event also fires.

In the `StudentsDataGridView_CellClick` event, I have lots of code to be done and so I just want them to be done when the user clicks the cell, not column header. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `StudentsDataGridView_CellContentClick` event, pal.